# MongoDB reformat / flatten document after $group and $lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, document, reduce

I have some data, products and they have the values of attributes and the `id` of that attribute.
The labels of the attributes are in the same collection but with `type: "attribute"` instead of `type: "product". I need to join those so I have the products including the label of the attributes and their values.

I have **very simple sample data** her: https://gist.github.com/flowl/632243bca8f2907a672f66920ea0f793

My aggregation looks like this:

```
db.input.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$attributes"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "input",
            localField: "attributes.id",
            foreignField: "attributeId",
            as: "attributeLabels"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { "output": { $ne: [] } }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$productId",
            product: { "$first": "$$CURRENT"}
        }
    },
    { $group : { _id : "$product._id", data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }
]);
```

The problem is, I want to reformat the output from this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5899925339db9185f13432c4"),
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : 111,
            "product" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5899925339db9185f13432c4"),
                "type" : "product",
                "productId" : 111,
                "attributes" : {
                    "id" : 1,
                    "value" : "L"
                },
                "attributeLabels" : [
                    {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5899927539db9185f13432cb"),
                        "type" : "attribute",
                        "attributeId" : 1,
                        "label" : "Size"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5899925339db9185f13432c4"),
    "type" : "product",
    "productId" : 111,
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5899927539db9185f13432cb"),
            "type" : "attribute",
            "attributeId" : 1,
            "label" : "Size",
            "value" : "L"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is your mongo db version ?

Comment: @Veeram db.version() - 3.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of below aggregation.

This will replace the `id` field value in the `attributes` array with the `$lookUp` value.

The response is not exactly similar but it includes all the attribute values from `product`.

```
db.input.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$attributes"
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "input",
        localField: "attributes.id",
        foreignField: "attributeId",
        as: "attributes.id"
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        "attributes.id": {
            $ne: []
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$attributes.id"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        type: {
            "$first": "$type"
        },
        productId: {
            "$first": "$productId"
        },
        attributes: {
            "$push": "$attributes"
        }
    }
}]);
```

Sample Response

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5899925339db9185f13432c4"),
    "type": "product",
    "productId": 111,
    "attributes": [{
        "id": {
            "_id": ObjectId("5899927539db9185f13432cb"),
            "type": "attribute",
            "attributeId": 1,
            "label": "Size"
        },
        "value": "L"
    }]
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but has 1 problem: the new attributes array replaces the original one instead of getting merged. Mean, the `value` field in the attribute gets lost.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: The first $group with `"$first": "$$CURRENT"` makes my attributes array have only a single element instead of all (like product 111 has 2 attributes), how can I fix this?

Comment: Updated answer should work the intended way. Please verify.

Comment: It wasn't 100% correct but I could use it to solve my problem and build exactly what I described in the question. Thanks for your help!! See the solution here: https://gist.github.com/flowl/fd647fd9370c51049ae4cc63b7acc1e4

Comment: Glad I can help. Pleas feel free to update my answer.